# How to reduce the runtime for pandas rolling taking too long run on multiple columns - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am working on a `timeseries` data. I am trying to apply the percentage change to the data.

Here is a snapshot of the data:

```
Time                     EX  SC      WH      YE Lt   Ub     Yl_2    Wm      Wm_2    value
2016-02-15 11:54:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.38    755 232 0.009   0.11    1428    1020    FALSE
2016-02-15 11:55:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.38    755 232 0.009   0.111   1436    1018    FALSE
2016-02-15 11:56:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.38    755 232 0.014   0.113   1471    1019    FALSE
2016-02-15 11:57:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.37    755 232 0.015   0.111   1457    1015    FALSE
2016-02-15 11:58:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.38    755 232 0.013   0.111   1476    1019    FALSE
2016-02-15 11:59:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.36    755 232 0.013   0.114   1416    1015    FALSE
```

The shape of the data is `(122334, 10)`

Here is my function:

```
def percent_change(series):
    # Collect all *but* the last value of this window, then the final value
    previous_values = series[:-1]
    last_value = series[-1]

    # Calculate the % difference between the last value and the mean of earlier values
    percent_change = (last_value - np.mean(previous_values)) / np.mean(previous_values)
    return percent_change
```

Applying the function here:

```
df2 = df.rolling(10).apply(percent_change)
```

Takes forever, please what am I doing wrong? Or how should I do it instead?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859794/rolling-percentage-change-in-python-data-frame) helps.

Comment: did you benchmark which step is critical? I mean, `rolling` for individual columns, the `apply` of your function?

Comment: @MrFuppes thats what I am doing now. I am now trying to loop through rather than at once since its not working

Comment: @JA-pythonista Did you manage to understand what the problem was? I tried to build a dataframe with the same shape as yours and used this snippet of code: `df.select_dtypes(['int', 'float']).rolling(10).apply(percent_change)`. Basically I applied the custom function `percent_change` only on numerical columns. This snippet of code ran in only 10 seconds on my laptop.